# How to write a variable in to file in ant?

Tags: ant

i have a variable `abc` and had the value `this is ant script`. This abc variable will keep on changing.

**Using ANT script, how can i write the value out to the file?**

Comment: What do you mean by 'variable'?  Ant properties are not mutable.

Answer (score 45):

The echo task in ANT is able to write to files

```
<echo file="output.txt" append="true">
   abc=${abc}
</echo>
```

Comment: Here's the [official docs for the echo task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echo.html).

Answer (score 30):

Use [propertyfile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html) task. An example taken from ant manual:

```
<propertyfile file="my.properties">
  <entry  key="abc" value="${abc}"/>
</propertyfile>
```

This may be better than `echo` as it updates the properties file with a given value, while `echo` appends to or overwrites the whole file.