# Regex select pattern

Tags: regex, ant, pattern-matching

My requirement is like below :-
I have one input file abc.properties having content like:-

CLASSPATH=\modules\oracle.xdk_12.1.3\xmlparserv2.jar

Timestamp connectToServer Start: 2015-10-21 16:03:05.862999
Successfully connected to managed Server "WLS_SOA1" that belongs to domain "soa_domain".

Following 43 composites are currently deployed to the platform:

1. Helloworld[1.0], partition=default, mode=active, state=on, isDefault=true, deployedTime=2015-08-12T21:58:15.289-07:00
2. TimeCall[1.0], partition=default, mode=active, state=on, isDefault=true, deployedTime=2015-09-06T01:36:03.908-07:00
3. StatusProcess[1.0], partition=default, mode=active, state=on, isDefault=true, deployedTime=2015-09-30T17:50:22.108-07:00

....

Output should be :-

Helloworld[1.0]

TimeCall[1.0]

StatusProcess[1.0]

Comment: This may help: 
`([^\[]+\[[^\]]+\])`

Comment: Thanks Mayur.  I'm trying below code:-   <concat destFile="bcd.properties">
            <fileset file="abc.properties"/>
         
            <filterchain>
             <linecontainsregexp>
                    <regexp pattern="([^\[]+\[[^\]]+\])" />
                </linecontainsregexp> 
             
            </filterchain>
        </concat>

Comment: Won't this work? [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yS3fO0/1) very simple version

Comment: Helloworld[1.0], partition=default, mode=active, state=on, isDefault=true, deployedTime=2015-08-12T21:58:15.289-07:00  
TimeCall[1.0], partition=default, mode=active, state=on, isDefault=true, deployedTime=2015-09-06T01:36:03.908-07:00
StatusProcess[1.0], partition=default, mode=active, state=on, isDefault=true, deployedTime=2015-09-30T17:50:22.108-07:00

Comment: I think, Mayur's pattern is right, however , I'm not using it in a right way to extract the desired output..

Comment: Hi benjamin, it could be [2.0], [3.0]  .. also possible.

Comment: allright check updated link [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yS3fO0/2)

Comment: Thanks Benjamin for quick help. Pattern is correct. Could you please suggest me how  to store the output of matched patterns values in some file  using ant only.

Comment: I have no experience with ant, but writing variables to a text file should work like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4684931/5210798)

Comment: @ Mayur:- Could you please help here...

Comment: Sorry! I am not familiar with ant.